# Does Debian or Ubuntu have a means of logging apt/aptitude commands?

Tags: logging, apt, aptitude, dpkg

Does Debian or Ubuntu have  a means of logging apt/aptitude commands?

I could also ask the same about yum commands in Redhat?

Do they have a history file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should look at `/var/log/apt/history.log`. But you might find more details in `/var/log/dpkg.log`.

Answer (score 2):

You'll find quite a bit of apt logs under /var/log/apt/

(Not exactly about commands being run. More about actions being taken.)